# Return type of generic method (Java)

Tags: java, generics

I have this generic function:

```
public static <T extends Number> T sum(List<T> list){
    Number tot = 0;
    for(Number n: list){
        tot = tot.doubleValue() +  n.doubleValue();
    }
    return (T)tot;
}
```

Recall from the main with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> listInt = new ArrayList<>();
    listInt.add(3);
    listInt.add(5);
    listInt.add(6);
    listInt.add(8);
    System.err.println("Sum: " + Calcolatrice.sum(listInt))
}
```

I therefore expect (being listInt an ArrayList of integers) that the value returned by the function sum is T = Integer and that in this case, give me a conversion error from Double to Integer.
The type of the result is instead Double and no error is thrown.
The cast (T)tot does not have the desired result.

I suppose it's because Java handles generics stance phase, but someone knows better explain why it works this way?

Comment: [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) is the term that explains that behaviour....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *return* type of `Calcolatrice.sum(listInt)` is actually `Integer` thanks to the cast at the end of `sum` in your example. However the real type of the result is `Double`. Obviously this is not a good situation, but it happened because you explicitly told the compiler in the cast that the return value would have the same type as the return value.

This situation means that if you were to instead write `Calcolatrice.sum(listInt).toString()` you would get a `ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` because you would be calling `Integer.toString()` on a `Double`. What your code is actually doing is `System.out.println("Sum: "+ String.valueOf(Calcolatrice.sum(listInt)))` which works because it downcasts to `Object` (thus resolving the conflict) before calling `toString`.

As @TmTron points out you cannot cast between `Double` and `Integer` boxed types in the same way that you can do with primitives.

i.e.

```
int i = (int) 2.0;
```

follows different rules from:

```
Integer i = (Integer) new Double(2.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

The Generics are only used at compilation to make sure you are not making mistakes in your code : Here, the parameter is `List<T>`, and the receiving variable must be of type `T`. That's all.

During runtime, `T` doesn't exist, and `tot` is a not an instance of `T`; it's a `Number`.

You can use `T` inside your method to receive the undefined instances but, for example, you can't make a `new T()`.

Answer (score 3):

When you look at the type hierarchy you see that both `Integer` and `Double` are children of `Number`: so they are siblings and you cannot directly cast `Double` to `Integer`:

```
    Double testDbl = 3.14;
    Integer testInt = (Integer)testDbl; // this will NOT compile
```

The compiler cannot know for sure, if the cast in the return statement of your `sum` function will work or fail: but the compiler will show a warning:

```
Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Number' to 'T'
```

Because of the hard-cast `(T)tot`, the compiler will simply take it for granted that your function returns an `Integer` (which it does not).

And finally, because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), there is no runtime check.